# Access property with define()'d token?

Tags: php, class, oop, member

I'd like to do this:

```
<?php
define('X', 'attribute_name');
// object $thing is created with member attribute_name
echo $thing->X;
?>
```

Attempting `$thing->X`, PHP takes X to be a property of $thing, and ignores the fact (rightly so) that it's a define()'d token.  That in mind, I had expected `$thing->{X}` to work, but no dice.

The only solution I'v come up with is to use a man-in-the-middle variable, like so:

```
$n = X;
echo $thing->$n;
```

But this extra step seems fairly un PHP-esque.  Any advice on a more graceful solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo $thing->{X};
```

seems to work for me. Here was my test script:

```
define('FOO', 'test');

$a = new stdClass();
$a->test = 'bar';

echo $a->{FOO};
```

outputs 'bar'.

Comment: Yeah... now this is working for me as well.  Must have been something else - at any rate, thanks; I'm glad to know I'm not completely insane yet!